# MIPS Floating Point Squaring Resulting in 0

Tags: floating-point, mips, mars-simulator

I'm working on an assignment where the first task set is to calculate the frobeneous norm (sum of squares) of the difference of two matrices. I'm trying to do this with single precision floating points, but I'm getting some weird results when squaring my floating points. This occurs in the `frobeneousNorm` Label at line 276. For instance, I've loaded in the value of the first indices of my difference matrix into my `$t3` register (should be about 8060928). I then use `mtc1 $t3 $f4` to convert this value to a single precision floating point, which, when checking the registers, stores a value `1.1295766E-38` in `$f4`. I then use `mul.s $f7 $f4 $f4` to multiply the floating point value by itself. However, when I check the value in `$f7` afterwards, it reads as `$f7    0.0`. I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here and any help would be appreciated. I've posted the code snippet below, and note that the comment is a signature where `$a0` holds the difference matrix (floating point where every byte is a new indices) and `$a1` is the row size of the difference matrix (64 in this instance, so a 4096 indice matrix of 64 x 64).

```
# TODO: float frobeneousNorm( float* A, int N )
frobeneousNorm: la $t0 ($a0)
        move $t1 $a1
        mul $t1 $t1 $t1
        li $t2 0
        li $t3 0
        li $t4 0
        li $t5 0
        mtc1 $zero $f6 
        mtc1 $zero $f7
        frobLoop:   beq $t2 $t1 frobLeave
                lw $t3 ($t0)
                mtc1 $t3 $f4
                mul.s $f7 $f4 $f4
                add.s $f6 $f6 $f7  
                addi $t0 $t0 4
                addi $t2 $t2 1
                j frobLoop
                
        frobLeave:  sqrt.s $f0 $f6
                jr $ra
```

Comment: I don't know if MARS simulates that behavior, but in some versions of the MIPS architecture you cannot use the destination register of an `mtc1` in the instruction immedately following it. Also note that you could replace `lw` + `mtc1` with `lwc1`.

Comment: What do you expect to get from multiplying 1E-38 by itself in single precision floating point?  Hint: check the range of single precision float.

Comment: Note: I recommend using only even register numbers when doing toy single precision stuff in MARS, b/c then you can more easily switch to double precision if you want to try that out...

Comment: @ErikEidt is that `1.1295766E-38` the correct value for `8060928`? When I end the program, even after going through 4096 entries, I end with NaN, which means I'm taking the `sqrt.s` of 0.